# `res.jsonx()` is deprecated in Sails v1.0 and will be removed in a future release

Tags: sails.js

While trying to install an Existing SailsJS App ,getting the Error - `res.jsonx()` is deprecated in Sails v1.0 and will be removed in a future release.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `res.jsonx()` with `res.json()`.

Comment: Source: https://sailsjs.com/documentation/upgrading/to-v-1-0#response-methods